# How to capitalize the first letter of your name in java?

Tags: java

Here is my code:
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
class namedisplay {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();

    String capital1 = name.substring(0).toUpperCase();
    String capital2 = name.substring(5).toUpperCase();

    System.out.println(capital1+capital2);



}
}
```

The program output:
Enter your name: 
**anna lee**
ANNA LEELEE

What I want the program to do is to capitalize only the first letters of the first name and last name, for example, Anna Lee.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
String name = input.nextLine(); 

String newName = "";

newName += name.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
newName += name.substring(1, name.length());

System.out.println(newName);
```

To get the first letter and capitalize, you use this `name.charAt(0).toUpperCase();`.
Then add that to the `newName`.

Then you want to add the remaining letters from `name` to `newName`. You do that by adding a `substring` of `name`

```
name.substring(1, name.length());  // 1 mean the substring will start at the 
                                   // second letter and name.length means the 
                                   // substring ends with the last letter
```

Comment: it says "cannot invoke toUpperCase() on the primitive type char", what should I do now?

Comment: Get the substring instead of charcter: `name.substring(0, 1);`

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Disagreed.